# DataContractSerializer ignore by default

Tags: c#, serialization

Want seralization to be an "opt-in" process so that only fields with a `[DataMember]` attribute show up in the xml.

Looked at DataContractSerializerSettings, but doesn't seem to have anything.  Tried below for kicks and giggles, but the xml still contained properties that did not have the `[DataMember]` attribute...

```
  DataContractSerializer writer = 
    new DataContractSerializer( typeof( ProductAAnimals ), 
    new DataContractSerializerSettings()
    {
        IgnoreExtensionDataObject = true
    } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .NET 3.5 SP1, Members decorated with [`DataMember`], any public read/write property will be serialized automatically by the `DataContractSerializer`. In order to opt-out, you have to go with private members. This wasn't the case before .NET 3.5 where only members decorated with [`DataMemeber`] are serialized.

More on what's new in .NET 3.5 SP1
[Blog](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2008/05/wcf-related-features-in-net-35-sp1-vs-2008-sp1.html).

Comment: Any chance you have an official m$ link describing this change?

Comment: @O.O, I don't have msdn link handy. However, I can quickly point a link to you (http://hyperthink.net/blog/we-are-pleased-to-bring-you-new-features-in-net-3-5-sp1/), which encloses some of the changes. Specifically point 3 under core framework.

Comment: Have you tried the [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

O
that's  not true  try to  take a look at this  code from  msdn  and try to  uncomment and comment the datamember attribute  in  class  person for  the property  LastName for example  an yot  will  see  that's not serialized as  @Nair  saied  . I think that you are trying to write to the same file  but the file it's locked  so  you will think that all properties are serialized.  try to change  the  name  every  time  and you will see  that property not marked with  datamember attribute will  not be serialized

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

    // You must apply a DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute 
// to a class to have it serialized by the DataContractSerializer.
[DataContract()]
class Person : IExtensibleDataObject
{
private string LastNameValue;
// Apply the DataMemberAttribute to fields (or properties)  
// that must be serialized.
[DataMember()]
public string FirstName;

//[DataMember()]
public string LastName
{
    get { return LastNameValue; }
    set { LastNameValue = value; }
}

[DataMember(Name = "ID")]
public int IdNumber;

// Note that you can apply the DataMemberAttribute to  
// a private field as well.
[DataMember]
private string Secret;

public Person(string newfName, string newLName, int newIdNumber)
{
    FirstName = newfName;
    LastName = newLName;
    IdNumber = newIdNumber;
    Secret = newfName + newLName + newIdNumber;
}

// The extensionDataValue field holds data from future versions  
// of the type.  This enables this type to be compatible with  
// future versions. The field is required to implement the  
// IExtensibleDataObject interface. 

private ExtensionDataObject extensionDatavalue;

public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
{
    get
    {
        return extensionDatavalue;
    }
    set
    {
        extensionDatavalue = value;
    }
}
}

  public class Test
  {
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        WriteObject(@"DataMemberAttributeExample.xml");
        ReadObject(@"DataMemberAttributeExample.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
        "The serialization operation failed: {0} StackTrace: {1}",
        exc.Message, exc.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit....");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static void WriteObject(string filename)
{
    // Create a new instance of the Person class.
    Person p1 = new Person("Zighetti", "Barbara", 101);
    FileStream writer = new FileStream(filename,
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    DataContractSerializer ser =
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
    ser.WriteObject(writer, p1);
    writer.Close();
}

public static void ReadObject(string filename)
{
    // Deserialize an instance of the Person class  
    // from an XML file.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    DataContractSerializer ser =
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
    // Deserialize the data and read it from the instance.
    Person deserializedPerson = (Person)ser.ReadObject(fs);
    fs.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}, ID: {2}",
    deserializedPerson.FirstName, deserializedPerson.LastName,
    deserializedPerson.IdNumber));
    }

}
```